# Ensure JQuery Hover Effect Reverts on Mouse Exit (Even When Initial Hover Effect Isn't Complete)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to scale down a child div when it is hovered on, and when the mouse exits, the child div is scaled up. I have it working, but I'm running into an issue when I enter and exit the child div BEFORE the initial scale down effect is complete. If I enter and exit the child div too quickly, the child div does not scale back up. I know I can do this with CSS, but in this particular instance, I need the JQuery to work.

I set up a simple JSFiddle to show what I'm going through. If you enter and exit the blue box (in the fiddle) very quickly (as in exit before the box scales down), you can see that blue box does not reappear.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n03ssvw/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id = "block-example">   
   <div id = "inner-block">   
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#block-example{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   padding:10px;
   background:red;
}

#inner-block{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background:blue;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#block-example').hover(function () {
  $(this).children().hide({effect: 'scale', duration: 100});
},function(){
  $(this).children().show({effect: 'scale', duration: 100});
});
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is, by changing the version of jQuery (1.10 +), its working fine. give it a try in same fiddle.

Comment: If you use the JQuery without the UI, then the scale effect doesn't work the way it should. It scales down to the top left of the box. If you use 1.9 with the UI enabled, you can see that the box scales down with the origin being at the center. The JQuery UI is required for JQuery effects to work properly.